# How can different 2fa authenticators work for the same app service?

Tags: two-factor-authentication

I encountered this registration process online where I received a QR code, and the instructions said to "use any authenticator app, like Google Authenticator or Authy". I was surprised to see that Microsoft authenticator app worked. Aren't their implementations different? How can different applications generate the same results on the same input if they don't have the same logic? If they have the same logic, why have different applications and what guarantees that they will stay identical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Authenticator, Microsoft Authenticator, and many others (Authy, Authenticator+, Aegis, etc...) all support TOTP and use the same algorithm (HMAC-based One-Time Password a.k.a HOTP) which  was published by the Internet Engineering Task Force.

This allows software developers to build an app that supports this protocol and thus it is not proprietary.

For more details the Wikipedia page is pretty decent. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-Time_Password